# Bash script to get php version

Tags: php, bash, path, version

I would like to get the current numerical value for php in the php.ini path.  I understand that php -v gets me a bunch of info, but I just need the "7.2" or whatever the current version is from the php.ini path.

Edit: I'm building an automation script and if the version changes, I need to be able to know what was installed when I ran `apt-get install php`

This script gets me the line i care about:

```
php --ini | grep Loaded | cut -d' ' -f12
```

The result (as of today) is

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Whats the best in bash way to echo `"7.2"` assuming that the `/etc/php` will not change (its unlikely based on the history of where php installs using apt-get)

I'm open to other methods that don't involve php --ini, I just need the 7.2 (or whatever that path value may morph into).

Comment: what's wrong with using `php --version`?

Comment: I need just the 7.2  as in `php_dev=php$php_version-dev,  apt-get -y install $php_dev`. I'm building an automation script and if the version changes, I need to be able to know what was installed when I ran `apt-get install php`

Comment: You have to be careful as the CLI and web versions may be different.  Not sure if this affects your circumstances but can be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building your automations with apt, then you should be relying on apt and/or dpkg to get the relevant information.

```
dpkg -l 'php*' | grep ^ii
```

For completenes, yum/dnf/rpm:

```
rpm -qa 'php*'
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I asked, I realized I could just adjust the delimiter and look for the 4th item.

```
php --ini | grep Loaded | cut -d'/' -f4
```

Answer (score 0):

This way uses CLI

```
php -r "echo substr(phpversion(),0,3);"
```

OR

```
php -r "echo implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', PHP_VERSION),0,2));"
```